# In a monomolecular reaction, how can a reactant experience collision to react?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Monomolecularity means no molecules which experience collision with each other taking part in reaction. So how it is possible that in monomolecular reaction only one reactant experiences collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *reactant*, e.g. O<sub>3</sub>, a pure chemical species, has many *molecules* that are in continual motion and can collide with each other (as well as with the walls of a container or with a catalyst), so you'll get some O<sub>2</sub> generated. Or the converse, if you have UV photons colliding with pure O<sub>2</sub> gas.